# Greatest value of $\frac{1}{4\sin \theta-3 \cos \theta+6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

State the greatest value of $$\frac{1}{4\sin \theta-3 \cos \theta+6}$$

Can anyone give me some hints on this?

Comment: You can try to use derivation in order to find the extremal values of this function.

Comment: Hint : $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$

Comment: Is it $1$ the minimum value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: Use $$-\sqrt {a^2+b^2} \le a\sin \theta + b \cos \theta \le \sqrt {a^2+b^2}$$.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$4\sin\theta - 3\cos\theta = 5\sin(\theta - \arctan\frac 34)$

$-1 \leq \sin\alpha \leq 1$

Comment: Can you explain in detail? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the manipulation in the first step? Any expression of the form $a\sin \theta \pm b\cos\theta$ can be expressed as $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin (\theta \pm \arctan \frac ba)$. The second part uses the bounds of the sine function. To maximise the ratio, find the minimum possible value of the denominator. Now figure out what that must be.

Answer (score 3):

$$4\sin\theta-3\cos\theta$$ is the dot product of the vector $(-3,4)$ with the unit vector in direction $\theta$. This dot product is minimized when the two vectors are antiparallel, and equals minus the product of the norms, i.e. $-5$.

The requested maximum is $$\frac1{-5+6}.$$